# What is the best way to clean a cloth mousepad?

Tags: mouse

I have a SteelSeries QcK mousepad (cloth), and I've notice that it's been getting dirtier and dirtier from regular use. What would be the best way to clean this using common household cleaning supplies?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has nothing to do with gaming.

Comment: @pppery I believe this counts as "game-specific hardware" as mentioned in our help page, and is on-topic. https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I'd say figure out what the manufacturer recommends, and make sure you're not doing something to void your warranty.

Since it's cloth, and likely much of the crud is oil-based from your skin, I'd recommend a mild detergent, like what you'd use in the washing machine.  Get it wet and rub a tiny bit of detergent into it, then rinse thoroughly and set on a rack or hang to dry.  If you're concerned about damaging it, use a detergent designed for gentle cycles.  Woolite is a brand that's pretty commonly available in the US, but it will probably vary wherever you are.

Comment: Finally had some free time and was able to clean my mousepad. The detergent worked like a charm. I used it with a bit of warm water and a washcloth to gently work some of the dirt out. Looks as good as new!

Answer (score 1):

Cold water should be enough, and shouldn't damage your pad.